# Simple MYSQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get my head around how I would do a particular MYSQL query but can't figure it out.

I have a table called developers and a table called plots. All of the plots have a developer id which links back to a developer name in the developers table.

I'm trying to output the developer name and then all the plots numbers under that developer. Once it's done that, I want it to do the same again with any more developers that may exist.

I've tried using joins however it will simply print:

developer name,       plot number,
developer name,       plot number,
developer name,       plot number,

I only need the developer name to display once. However I need to print all the plot numbers.

I thought about having some kind of IF statement in the while loop where if the developer name is the same as it was previously in the last loop then it wont print. However I can't seem to figure out how that would work.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Any code you can provide to show what you currently have?

Comment: SELECT developer_name AS developerName,COUNT(plot_number) plotNumber FROM tableName GROUP BY plotNumber

Comment: make [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do in two steps

```
1. to get developer name and id.
2. get all plots of that id

    $sql1 = "SELECT developer_id, developer_name FROM developers ";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $sql1);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
      $developer_id = $row['developer_id'];
      $developer_name = $row['developer_name'];

      echo $developer_name;

      $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM plots WHERE developer_id='$developer_id' ";
      $res2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
      while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2))
      { 
         echo $row2['plot_id'];
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the code that I used in the end

$sql1 = "SELECT developer_id, developer_name FROM developers"; 
$res = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql1); 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { 
 $developer_id = $row['developer_id']; $developer_name = $row['developer_name'];

echo $developer_name;

$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM plots WHERE development_id='$developer_id' ";
 $res2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $sql2); 
 while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)) { 
  echo $row2['plot_number']; 
 } 
};

Comment: However, is this really the best way to go about completing the task?

Answer (score 0):

This won't give you an output as exactly u need. But maybe this would do the job.

```
select developer_name, group_concat(plot_number SEPARATOR ',') from developer inner join plot on plot.developer_id = developer.developer_id group by developer_name
```

You can then explode out(PHP Explode with comma as the delimiter) the plot_number column from the result set to show all the plot numbers corresponding to a developer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Left Join..

```
Select * From developers Left Join plots on developers.developerid=plots.developerid
```

So it'll select everything from table developers and for each developer, it should select the plots.

Use an if condition to check if the last result of the developer id is equal to the current. If it is no, print the id.

**Edit:**
Here's how the PHP program should run..

```
$strSQL = "Select * From developers Left Join plots on developers.developerid=plots.developerid";
$Result = mysql_query($strSQL);
$DevID = "";
while ($Fields = mysql_fetch_array($Result))
    {
    if ($Fields["developerid"] != $DevID)
        {
        echo $Fields["developerid"];
        $DevID = $Fields["developerid"];
        }
    echo $Fields["plot_column"];
    }
```

Comment: How would you go about checking what the last result was to compare it to the current one?

Comment: The recent edit to the answer has it all. The if condition does a simple check.